# How does the Greek 'legein' relate to PIE *leg 'to collect'?

Tags: proto-indo-european, greek

> ENTRY: leg-
>   DEFINITION: To collect; with derivatives meaning “to speak.” Oldest form *le-, becoming *leg- in centum languages.
>   [...]
>   3. lexicon, logion, –logue, –logy; alexia, analects, anthology, catalog, dialect, dialogue, dyslexia, eclectic, eclogite, eclogue, horologe, lectotype, prolegomenon, **from Greek *legein*, to gather, speak, with o-grade derivative *logos*, a gathering, speech** (see also 6 below for derivatives independently built to *logos*).

Initially, I was researching the etymology of the suffix [-logy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-logy).
What connects the Greek *legein* with the PIE root **leg-**?

My guess is this: In Ancient Greek, if one wanted to speak to many people, then these people must be gathered together. I doubt my guess, because I am unsure if the sense of collection refers to some historical particularity of speech, such as the collection of certain rhetoric. My doubt is worsened by my former ignorance of early ways of reading, [when I asked this question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/239785/50720).

Comment: It wasn't just in Ancient Greek, cf. Latin legere "collect; gather; read". de Vaan 2002 argues that "The semantic shift probably went from 'gather, collect' (also in * disligere 'to pick out' > 'love') to 'watch out for, care for' (neglegere), 'concentrate on' (intellegere) and finally to 'read'. A similar shift took place in Greek."

Comment: And it's not the most interestring semantic shift regardig "to speak". Both Ancient Greek and Russian have a semantic shift where "to rub" means "to speak" (Greek *διατριβή* vs. Russian *peretirat*) :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how much has bern written about the first words of genesis, *in the brginning there was logos*? Finally it clicks for me, they were hunter gatherers! Maybe.

Comment: That's not Genesis! It's in the Gospels (Christian bible), not the Hebrew bible.

Comment: yup, Genesis begins "in the beginning, G-d created the heavens and the earth"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic meaning of the root *leǵ- was "pick out". Compare e.g., from Latin, *se-lect, col-lect*: to collect things is to pick them out (*legō*) and place them together (*con-*).
In Greek, the development seems to have been something like "pick out (information)" > "recount" > "say". If you're telling someone a story, you start by picking out the things you want to tell them.
The semantic relationship is possibly a bit clearer if you think about the noun from the same root *logos*, which means "verbal account": an account is a collection of information that the speaker has picked out for some communicative purpose.

(The reddit thread quoted in your answer is a bit misleading in that in Greek, unlike in Latin, *legō* hardly ever means "read", while in Latin it doesn't mean "say": the developments in the two languages were not the same, though both senses start from the idea of "picking out".)

Comment: compare two closely related branches, ignore wildly differing meaning in other branches, rely on totality of sound change, ignore uncertainty of the chronology, ignore comparable roots, omit internal derivation. Well done. Next step: deny extra IE comparisons. Now on to read the second sentence.

Comment: Nothing more to add, after all, except an anecdota: The Finnish Kalevala tells of a hero who amongst other tasks, travels the lands to seek spells. So metal.

Comment: @vectory I'm afraid your objections are almost as mysterious to me as the allusion to the Kalevala. What "wildly differing meaning in other branches", and how could this be relevant to a semantic development within Greek? What does "totality of sound change" mean and what does it have to do with my answer, which doesn't mention sound change? What uncertain chronology? What comparable roots? Etc.

Comment: Oh, I just happened to read about the Kalevala a day before. These things always work their way into relevance for. The acquisition of first hand witnes accounts--re-porting so to speak--has of course always been critical, as far as tradition goes back. The specific finnish language material might be entirely besides the point, sure, I don't know.

Comment: »What "wildly differing meaning in other branches"«? Tocharian "look, see", Iranian "forrest" (possibly); Now, 
 had wholly ignored Albanian, as is usual, because it's too uncertain, but lets take a peek: "to read" is surely from areal influence, "to choose" might be in line with "to look" and show an older meaning in line with Toch. in an uncertain chronology, "to gather; fasten; collect; convene; (intransitive) to fuster, pus up" is right there, but maybe areal, and \*ledh could go to \*les along with Ger. *lesen*, w.r.t. *letzen, lieren, lösen, Los, leren* cp. *to lose* and *draw lots*.

Comment: @vectory The Albanian meaning "gather" is basically the same as in Greek and Latin; the relation of the Tocharian and Iranian words to this root seems to be in doubt precisely because of their differing meanings. But again, I can't see what any of this has to do with the *Greek-internal* semantic development my answer describes.

Comment: you are twisting the facts. If there's a "*Greek-internal* semantic development", you wouldn't need to refer to no PIE root instead of the alleged Greek internal evidence. This is aggrevating, and not the way it shoukd work. It honours the question though, and, quite perplexing, Beekes fully agrees, "the thematic root stem present [*lego*], from which all stem forms and nominal derivatives are derived, …" agrees, although "'to collect, gather' (Il.; Att. prose only prefixed), 'to count, recount' (Il.) …" implies that both were already in the Ilyad.

Comment: PS: cp. Alb. *mbledh* and Homer's *Ilyad*, wtf.

Comment: to wit: a) "Wilusa, (Hittite:  URUwi5-lu-ša) … The city is often identified with the Troy of the Ancient Greek Epic Cycle … Ilios and Ilion (Ἴλιος, Ἴλιον), which are alternate names for Troy in the Ancient Greek language, are linked etymologically to Wilusa." [[en.wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilusa)] b) the *-LU-* Cunieform from Sumerian can be read "lu "ABUNDANT" (…) wr. lu "(to be) abundant; to heap up" Akk. dêšu; kamāru 1. …
2. to heap up
Akk. dêšu "to sprout"; kamāru **"to pile up, accumulate"**." [[PSD/UPenn](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e3352.html)].

Comment: @vectory If there is an argument behind your quotes from random Wikipedia etc. articles, I can't make it out, so I think we should drop the discussion.

Comment: refer to my first comment: "Next step: deny extra IE comparisons.". To be honest, I don't quite believe it myself because it is rather random (the idea was that the Ilias is a poem, a tale, writing, a collected work), but it would support your argument.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from https://redd.it/6k9usb that answers this question.

> [razlem](https://old.reddit.com/user/razlem). [61 points 3 years ago](https://old.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/6k9usb/pie_le%C7%B5_to_gather_kept_that_meaning_in_latin/djkef36/).
>
> The semantic shift isn't that big: reading something = gathering information. Even in English you have "I reckon" being interchangeable with "I gather".

[AllanBz comments on How did 'putare' evolve to include all these meanings?](https://old.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/35o8vx/how_did_putare_evolve_to_include_all_these/cr6gaam/)

> A similar thing happened with Greek *logos*, thought, word, etc. *Lego* originally meant "gather." It is cognate with *legere* and *legio* (legion), a "levy," and collect (which is also used metaphorically, to recollect is to remember). A similar metaphorical construction is used today with gather: "I gather she will not join us tonight."

Comment: There's the nativevspeaker instinct bias. Of course it's a *huge* semantic shift. Otherwise you wouldn't have had to ask. Don't let yourself be willified. It's s good question that has to be asked.

Comment: @vectory Thanks for your support! I hope your answer, if revised, can be restored?